# MYSQL get substring

Tags: amazon-athena

I'm trying to get substring dynamically and group by it. So if my `uri` column contains records like: `/uri1/uri2` and `/somelongword/someotherlongword` I would like to get everything up to second delimiter, namely up to second `/` and count it. I'm using this query but obviously it is cutting string statically (6 letters after the first one).

```
SELECT substr(uri, 1, 6) as URI,
         COUNT(*) as COUNTER
FROM staging
GROUP BY substr(uri, 1, 6)
ORDER BY COUNTER DESC
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `SUBSTRING()` and `POSITION()`

schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`uri` varchar(10))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`uri`)
VALUES
    ('some/text'),
    ('some/text1'),
    ('some/text2'),
    ('aa/bb'),
    ('aa/cc'),
    ('bb/cc')
;
```

query

```sql
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(uri,1,POSITION('/' IN uri)-1), 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(uri,1,POSITION('/' IN uri)-1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/293dd3/3/0

edit: here I found amazon athena documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html and here is the string function documentation: https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/string.html

my answer above still stands, but you might need to change `SUBSTRING` to `SUBSTR`

edit 2: it seems there's a special function to achieve this in amazon athena called `SPLIT_PART()`

query:

```sql
SELECT SPLIT_PART(uri, '/', 1), COUNT(*) FROM tbl GROUP BY SPLIT_PART(uri, '/', 1)
```

from docs:

```
split_part(string, delimiter, index) → varchar
Splits string on delimiter and returns the field index. Field indexes start with 1. If the index is larger than than the number of fields, then null is returned.
```

Comment: Yes, that would work but may values are with two slashes like so: `/some/text`

Comment: @Murakami what output do you expect when the value have 2 slashes? Even with 2 slashes it will still output the expected value (the first 'directory' on the uri/path)

Comment: If value is `/some/text` then counted result of `/some`

Comment: @Murakami is the leading ```/``` always there, or is it optional?

Comment: try this: ```SELECT SPLIT_PART(uri, '/', 1), COUNT(*) FROM tbl GROUP BY SPLIT_PART(uri, '/', 1)```